# How to get relationship data from a json object in laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel

I have two models 1. Subject 2.Condition. And between this i have ***1 to 1 relationship***.Now in the condition i have a foreign key subject_id andd which is in ***json*** format. Now i want get the the subject name which id stored in json format subject_id
Subject.php

```
class Subject extends Model
{
    protected $fillable=['name','department_id'];
    public function condition()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Condition::class);
    }
}
```

Condition.php

```
class Condition extends Model
{
    protected $fillable=['subject_id','department_id','total'];

    protected $casts=['subject_id' => 'array']

    public function subject()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Subject::class);
    }
}
```

And here i tried to get all the subject name form **json id's**

```
$condition=Condition::find(4);
        foreach ($condition->subject_id as $key => $subject) {
            $list[]=$subject->subject->name;
        }
        dd($list);
```

I want to know is it possible to retrieve the names of subject from json id and if it yes please help me to get it.

Comment: A foreign key "in json format." What does this mean? Whatever you're doing, it's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Try this:</strike>

```
foreach ($condition->subject->subject_id as $key => $subject) {
     $list[]=$subject->subject->name;
}
```

Comment: it gives me error like Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: Why are you using json format in subject_id field ? why don't you use juste an Integer?

Comment: i have a condition like you have 3 subjects physics,math and chemistry and to enroll a department i have to get total of 50/60 marks in these three subjects

Comment: ot worked bro it says Trying to get property 'subject_id' of non-object

Comment: What is the output of `var_dump($condition->subject)` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202095/discussion-between-y-jrb-and-tanvir-ahmed).

Answer (score 0):

Hey i get an idea to get this result like using below

```
$condition=Condition::find(4);
        $subjects=Subject::whereIn('id',$condition->subject_id)->get();
        dd($subjects);
```

If someone has the better approach to get this result please let us know